# How to build a matrix and turn columns as rows against the same columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, matrix

I need to create a matrix showing the amount of locations overlapping between the different stores. I have the following table A that I need to convert to a matrix format shown in example B

Table A

```
location | kfc | burger king | five guys | taco bell

Tokyo    | 1   | 0           | 1         | 1

Barcelona| 0   | 1           | 1         | 0

Texas    | 1   | 1           | 1         | 0

Bangkok  | 1   | 0           | 0         | 0
```

Intended output B showing matrix of overlapping locations (for example kfc and burgerking only coexist together in one city so the cell for it shows 1)

```
matrix | kfc | burgerk | fiveguys | taco bell

kfc    | null| 1       | 2        |  1

burgerk| 1   | null    | 2        |  0

fiveguy| 2   | 2       | null     | 1

taco be| 1   | 0       | 1        | null
```

This is just an example as the actual table has over 2 million rows of locations and about 50 stores.

Is there a way to do this in SQL without having to do a row left joining every single store, coding every count individually and then using union all to manually code the next row?